# Xterm giving error that DISPLAY is not set

Tags: x11-forwarding

```
$ xterm 
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:  
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

I connect to the server using `ssh -X user@server`. DISPLAY is not set

```
$ echo $DISPLAY

$
```

I am running Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is X11 forwarding enabled in your sshd config?

```
grep -i x11 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

You should have:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

If that's not the problem, try running ssh with "ssh -v" to get more debug output and post it here. It's also worth trying "ssh -Y".